# Can't seem to uninstall git

Tags: macos, git

I need to replace my git installation, but I can't even remove it.

I have found [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612326/how-do-i-uninstall-git-version-1-6-5-1-from-mac-os-x-10-5-8) all over, but they don't work.

```
git version 1.7.3.2
```

When I run the aforementioned solution, every line gives me

```
No such file or directory
```

I tried running the installer for 1.7.7 from [git-osx-installer](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/detail?name=git-1.7.7-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg&can=3&q=&sort=-uploaded), and it completes sucessfully, but makes no change to my git install. I have restarted the computer to see changes take effect to no avail.

Comment: And what does `which git` tell you?

Comment: It said `/opt/local/bin/git`

Comment: Here are the commands I ran http://see.weareinto.com/BUGS

Comment: Now it says `/usr/bin/git`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get this error because git isn't installed in `/usr/local/git`. Find out where it is with `which git`, and rm it with the correct location.

If you have a package manager (brew, fink or macports) you'll want to use its interface to remove it, if it was used for installation.

EDIT after your comment

`/opt/local/bin` is the location of software installed by [macports](http://www.macports.org/), so you'll want to run this:

```
sudo port uninstall git
```

Even if you have deleted by hand (which you shouldn't have, the original page  is misleading), it should be fully uninstalled

Comment: Now it says `/usr/bin/git`

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to remove the old version.  Grab the source tarball, unpack it into your home directory, and build it.  For example:

```
$ cd $HOME
$ tar zxf git-x.y.z.tar.gz
$ cd git-x.y.z
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME
$ make && make install  # (Can probably just do "make install")
```

That gives you a perfectly good version installed in $HOME.  Put $HOME/bin
in your PATH and you are good to go.

Comment: Now it says `/usr/bin/git`